# How to handle the NOT SET events of an Admob Interstitial ad in the DebugView of Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Hope someone can help me...

In my Android application (developed with Android Studio 3.3.1) I have the following flow:

1 - Show Activity A (ActivitySplashScreen). When an Interstitial ad is loaded, show it.

2 - When Interstitial is closed, finish Activity A and start Activity B (ActivityPrincipal)

My problem is that during this process, I receive two events "NOT SET" related to the ad that I do not know how to avoid appearing or how to change the name NOT SET for another:

[image: Problem Illustration]

I'm using these implementations:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

This depencende:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

And my code is as following:

In activity A I prepare the interstitial and show it according to this code:

```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onAdImpression() {
            super.onAdImpression();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) 
        {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            Log.i("SPLASH SCREEN", "Error cargando Ad");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() 
        {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            Log.i("SPLASH SCREEN", "Ad Cargado");
        }           

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() 
        {
            super.onAdClosed();
            Log.i("SPLASH SCREEN", "Ad Cerrado");

            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent().setClass(ActivitySplashScreen.this, ActivityPrincipal.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entrada_activity, R.anim.salida_activity);
        }           

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() 
        {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();
            Log.i("SPLASH SCREEN", "Ad Left Application");
        }
    });

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
    {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
```

Note that if I do not show the Interstitial and I directly finish Activity A and start Activity B, these two "NOT SET" events do not appear in DebugView.

I hope I have provided enough information so that someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean your interstitial ads did not appear?

Comment: The interstitial is shown correctly. What I need to know is how to change the name of those "NOT SET" events that are being recorded in firebase.

Comment: @Amc Have you got solution for this. I am getting same issue. Please help.